# Firebase First Open event is not correct

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated Firebase to my app and using it for some time. I was getting similar first open result as iTunesConnect until 2 weeks ago. For 2 weeks I am getting weird analytics. Even my daily new download is about 500-600, Firebase Analytics says I get 10-20 first open. I didn't change any settings in Firebase or didn't update the app. All same. What happened recently to Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was recently a bug on the iOS side of things -- it started sometime around the last week in January -- that was under-reporting first_open events. It has since been corrected (via a server-side fix), and you should start seeing normal `first_open` results again. Sorry for the inconvenience!